# How to make a spring-batch job itself @JobScope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to make a `Job` itself a `@JobScope`?

I want to run a job periodically. The job itself should find a database id, and perform subsequent steps based on this id:

```
@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    Long id = dao.findSomeId();
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("name")
            .start(import())
            .next(step(id))
            .build();
}

private Step step(Long id) {
   return stepBuilder.get("step").tasklet(new Tasklet() {
        @Override execute() {
            //execute a task based on the id. Eg a database cleanup
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
   }).build();
}
```

Problem: the `dao.findSomeId()` statement is only executed once during first job initialization. Thereafter, the `id` always remains the same for any job execution.

Comment: Move the `dao.findSomeId();` call to within the actual job; failing that, create a facade for your job that does the ID lookup, then executes the job.

Comment: And how could I then pass this id to the job itself (which obviously needs the dynamic id on each execution).

Comment: Can you share more of your configuration (specifically, the step)?  I have a hunch that this can be accomplished in a better way.   In short, you can't have a Job that is Job scoped...

Comment: @MichaelMinella I often have this requirement. Eg if soem kind of cleanup job is to be run inside the `Job` as a `Step`. I added some pseudocode for a `Tasklet` step above that makes use of the id. The id could in fact be any object to work with.